# Returning JSON via REST for a @OneToMany fails with (formerly NullPointer) Exception

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a simple proof-of-concept demo using Spring Data REST / RestRepository architecture. I started with two entities:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    public Address() {}

    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true) 
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_ADDRESS_ID_GENERATOR")    
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_ADDRESS_ID_GENERATOR", strategy="native")  
    private int ID;

    //@RestResource(exported = false)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=domain.location.CityStateZip.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)   
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST}) 
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="CityStateZipID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false) }) 
    private domain.location.CityStateZip cityStateZip;

    @Column(name="StreetNo", nullable=true) 
    private int streetNo;

    @Column(name="StreetName", nullable=false, length=40)   
    private String streetName;

    <setters and getters ommitted>  
}
```

and for `CityStateZip`:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="CityStateZip")
public class CityStateZip {

    public CityStateZip() {}

    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true) 
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_CITYSTATEZIP_ID_GENERATOR")   
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_CITYSTATEZIP_ID_GENERATOR", strategy="native") 
    private int ID;

    @Column(name="ZipCode", nullable=false, length=10)  
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name="City", nullable=false, length=24) 
    private String city;

    @Column(name="StateProv", nullable=false, length=2) 
    private String stateProv;

}
```

with repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "addr", path = "addr") 
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Integer> {

     List<Address> findByStreetNoAndStreetNameStartingWithIgnoreCase(@Param("stNumber") Integer streetNo, @Param("street") String streetName);
     List<Address> findByStreetNameStartingWithIgnoreCase(@Param("street") String streetName);
     List<Address> findByStreetNo(@Param("streetNo") Integer strNo);
}
```

and:

```
// @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "zip", path = "zip", exported = false)
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "zip", path = "zip")
public interface CityStateZipRepository extends JpaRepository<CityStateZip, Integer> {

    List<CityStateZip> findByZipCode(@Param("zipCode") String zipCode);
    List<CityStateZip> findByStateProv(@Param("stateProv") String stateProv);
    List<CityStateZip> findByCityAndStateProv(@Param("city") String city, @Param("state") String state);
}
```

and main() code of

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
// @EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/etc/domain.location/application.properties" })
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

with this code, things work fine. I can save a CityStateZip and reference it while saving an Address, and can GET the resulting address. Step two was to add another class: An Address can have 0-to-many associated Remarks, while a Remark is tied to a single Address. That entity is:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="Remark")
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked" })
public class Remark implements Serializable {
    public Remark() {
    }

    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)  
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_REMARK_ID_GENERATOR") 
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES_REMARK_ID_GENERATOR", strategy="native")   
    private int ID;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=domain.location.Address.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)    
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="LocationID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false) }) 
    private domain.location.Address address_ix;

    @Column(name="Comment", nullable=false, length=255) 
    private String comment; 

    <getters, setters removed>
}
```

and a repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "remarks", path = "remarks")
public interface RemarkRepository extends JpaRepository<Remark, Integer> {
}
```

and I add this to Address:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="address_ix", targetEntity=domain.location.Remark.class)    
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)  
private java.util.Set remark = new java.util.HashSet();
```

I can retrieve the exposed API by doing GET .../addr if I do not have any Address instances. I can still save an Address instance to the database. But once I have a saved instance, doing a GET .../addr, or trying to GET the specific instance, I get an exception:

```
"timestamp": 1418423263313,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
"message": "Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap[\"addr\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap[\"addr\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])",
"path": "/addr"
```

I assume I am doing something wrong with the @OneToMany association in Address, or the @ManyToOne in Remark, or a combination of both. I have added a @ManyToOne, one-directional association to Address with no problems. What do I need to do to be able to retrieve Address data through GETs? What is JSON complaining about? (At this point, there was no Remark instance in the database. I even added a @JsonIgnore annotation in front of the @OneToMany, but I still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was due to auto-generated code. The declaration of the Set of remarks is missing the parameter calling out the type of Set (or HashSet). If I change the code to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="address_ix", targetEntity=domain.location.Remark.class)    
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)  
private java.util.Set<Remark> remark = new java.util.HashSet<Remark>();
```

the code now works as required. Without the parameter, the (Spring or JSON) code did not know how to process this member.